# How to print some output to terminal as well as to a file

Tags: ubuntu, groovy, terminal

I am running a program in groovy and I am saving it to a file, like this:

```
groovy program > output
```

However, I would like to track the progress of the program while it's running, is it possible to print some output also to the terminal?

Comment: Is the output you want to print to the terminal the same as the output you want to save to the File?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
groovy lol.groovy | tee lol.out
```

Comment: @user132290, was this answer helpful? If so, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to print separate status information that doesn't get redirected, print it to `System.err`, otherwise known as `stderr`, instead of the default `System.out`/`stdout`.

For example:

```
 println "this goes to stdout"
 System.err.println "this goes to stderr"
```

When you run the program, it can be redirected separately:

```
 $ groovy program.groovy
 this goes to stdout
 this goes to stderr
 $ groovy program.groovy > output
 this goes to stderr
 $ cat output
 this goes to stdout
 $ groovy program.groovy > output 2> error
 $ cat error
 this goes to stderr
```